# Is there a compactly supported function that its Fourier transfrom vanishes at given n real points?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

My question is as follows: Given ${{\lambda }_{1}},\,{{\lambda }_{2}},...,{{\lambda }_{n}}\in \mathbb{R}$ where $\underset{1\le j\le n-1}{\mathop{\min }}\,\left| {{\lambda }_{j+1}}-{{\lambda }_{j}} \right|\ge d>0$. Is there a compactly supported function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that its Fourier transform $\hat{f}$, defined by $\hat{f}\left( \lambda  \right)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}{f\left( x \right){{e}^{i\lambda x}}dx}$, satisfies $\hat{f}\left( {{\lambda }_{j}} \right)=0$, $j=1,...,n$ ? Thank you for helping.

Comment: Here is how to do it for one point $\lambda$. Take any two (nice) compactly supported functions $A,B$. Then consider a linear combination with $y\hat A(\lambda)+z\hat B(\lambda)=0$. Does this help? Another useful fact is that $\widehat{(f\star g)}=\hat f\cdot\hat g$.

Comment: user555, the method of @NAME_IN_CAPS allows one to construct a compactly supported $f_1$ whose FT vanishes at a prescribed $\lambda_1$. Do this for each $\lambda_j$. Then $f=f_1* f_2 *\dots*f_n$ has the properties you require.

Comment: Another suggestion: since the FT of the indicator function of the interval [-1,1] is something like $2\sin(\lambda)/\lambda$ you can easily tweak this to get a compactly supported function whose FT vanishes at a prescribed point.

Comment: Yes I understand your hint. These help me very much. Thank you very much.

Comment: In my "solution", one needs $A\neq cB$, if the linear combination is to be nonzero. Then again, perhaps a simpler solution to the originally stated exercise *is* just the zero function. I'm still trying to understand what the $\min$ condition is doing.

Comment: Similarly, since the space of compactly supported Fourier transformable functions is infinite dimensional, you can take such functions $F_i$ and then by linear algebra obtain $a_i$ such that $\sum_i a_i \hat F_i(\lambda_j)=0$ for all $j$ (which is what my original thought was, though I figured the convolution trick was mentionable). Again a requirement that $\sum_i a_iF_i$ is not identically zero is probably in order. But I'm most surprised that this question was simply closed for being too much like homework... My original comment was just to push the questioner in a good direction.

Answer (score 8):

The space $L^2(a,b)$ is a Hilbert space of infinite dimension. Therefore there is an
element $f\neq 0$ of this space which is orthogonal to $e^{i\lambda_j x}$. Take this $f$.
You can also find such $f$ is any finite dimensional subspace whose dimension is $>n$.
Just choose a basis and solve a system of linear equations.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but it could not be generalized to an infinite number of zeroes, a natural extension of the question. The Weierstrass factorization theorem allows to construct entire functions with prescribed zeroes and in some case these functions could be of exponential type, thus with compactly supported Fourier transforms, e.g $\sin z$.

Comment: You did not ask about infinitely many zeros. If you ask, I will answer.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the polynomial
$
P(\xi)=\prod_{1\le j\le n}(\xi-\lambda_j).
$
The inverse Fourier transform of $(\xi-\lambda_j)$ is 
$$
\int(\xi-\lambda_j) e^{2iπ x\xi} d\xi=(D_x-\lambda_j)(\delta_0)=\frac{\delta'_0}{2iπ}-\lambda_j\delta_0=T_j, \quad\text{support } T_j=\{0\},
$$
Let $F$ be the inverse Fourier transform of $P$:
we have
$$
F=T_1\ast\dots\ast T_n,\quad\text{support } F=\{0\},\quad \hat F= P.
$$
If $\rho$ is smooth compactly supported, the function $F\ast \rho$ is smooth compactly supported
and 
$$
\widehat{F\ast \rho}= P\hat \rho
$$
and thus vanishes at the $\lambda_j$. There are generalizations using the Weierstrass factorization theorem to construct entire functions with prescribed zeroes.

Answer (score 4):

The space of $W$ compactly supported continuous functions is infinite dimensional, and the map $f\mapsto (\widehat{f}(\lambda_1),\cdots,{\widehat f}(\lambda _n))$ which is a map from $W$ into ${\mathbb C}^n$ has a nonzero element in the kernel.